# Split tag's text contents into multiple tags based on a maximum height per tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So say you have a bunch of HTML you want to say that the maximum height of any given element is a fixed number. How would you split the element into multiple elements each no taller then the desired height per element limit? This obviously depends on the window width, so assume you have a sufficiently narrow window that makes the height of the element > the desired height.

**Start With**

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

**End With**

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type</p>
<p>specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: Are you doing this with something other than text? Because with text your browser should be handling this automatically if you set the `line-height` property.

Comment: Looks like you want to split a text to displayit in horizontal aligned columns, am I right?

Comment: I'm doing pagination and I need to take a potentially large div or p tag's text contents and split into multiple tags so each will fit on the screen. Most solutions split up pages by elements/tags and that doesn't help when you have one huge element.

Comment: Are you talking just about plain text or are there html elements like hyperlinks inside your text.

Comment: there can be hyperlinks, and basic things like lists, no pictures or block elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of approaching this problem, from the point of pagination, is to actually *"paginate"* the view of the element by way of scroll offset.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dr7Rv/

The following code basically creates as many duplicates of the original as required, and offsets the view of it's content each time by scrolling. This gives you seperate elements to play with and position as you'd like, just as you requested. Because of the way this works I've made the code support a pixel height or a line count -- because line count would look better.

```
$.fn.createPagedClones = function(measure, type){
  /// setup vars
  var p = $(this), i = 0, c, t, h = p.innerHeight();
  /// handle lines conversion to px
  ( type == 'lines' ) && ( measure *= parseFloat(p.css('line-height')) || 22 );
  /// create a re-usable css object
  c = {"height": measure+"px", "overflow": "hidden"};
  /// step each division and create an offset view
  do{
    /// clone our original, and create a new view by scroll
    t = ( t ? p .clone() .insertAfter(t) : p ) .css(c) .scrollTop(i);
    /// increment i
    i += measure;
    /// stop if we've done enough
  }while( Math.round(i) < h );
}

$(function(){    
  //$('.target-p-tag').createPagedClones(50, 'px');
  $('.target-p-tag').createPagedClones(3, 'lines');
});
```

Theoretically you could change the above so the code always worked on the original, meaning that your pagination system would pretty much scroll the content per page. But this version allows you to position each page where you'd like... you could have them side by side if you wished, however this might look a bit strange if you had any randomly sized elements i.e. images.

Answer (score 1):

just very draft illustrating the idea:

http://jsbin.com/irewop/2/edit

assuming if you going use html inside you need correct logic with splitting chunks in no breaking tag manner, probably using `domParser` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser, or some external library.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best solution, but it seems to work fine:

```
var height = 100;

$("p").each(function() {
    var words = this.innerHTML.split(" "),
        $p = $(this).empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if ($p.height() > height) {
            $p = $p.text(function(i, val) {
                return val.split(" ").slice(0, -2).join(" ");
            }).clone().empty().appendTo("div");
            i--;
        }
        $p[0].innerHTML += words[i] + " ";
    }
});​
```

In the current code `div` is a container of `<p>` element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RubCq/